# how to create radio button on pop up

Tags: javascript

Is there any possible way to create radiobutton in pop up display using javascript?

```
function selectradiobutton()
{
   ????
}
```

I only know how to create alert on javascript

```
function alert1()
{
   alert("please select one!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a `div` with `radio-buttons` inside, `add` appropriate `CSS` to design it and then keep it in the `HTML limbo` without attaching it. Bind the `attachment` to your event of choice.

You cannot use the `native JS alert` or `confirm` methods to include `radio buttons`, they are for `text` purposes only.

If you want `custom pop-ups`, use either something like [jQuery UI Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: hm actually I really dont get what you said, I dont understand. but I'll try using jQuery UI Dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Alerts can't do that, instead, use [jQuery Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

create a div with the desired design. then use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)